# Написать Linq-аналог запроса

Tags: c#, запрос, linq

Я хочу преобразовать этот SQL в LINQ, но сталкиваются с трудностями, может кто-нибудь мне помочь?

Вот SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
   SELECT id, id_hi, name, 1 AS lvl
   FROM public."Advertstypes"
   WHERE id_hi = 2
   UNION
   SELECT t.id, t.id_hi, t.name, r.lvl + 1 AS lvl
   FROM public."Advertstypes" AS t
      JOIN r ON t.id_hi = r.id
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

Comment: "Конвертировать" sql в linq плохая идея, опишите словами что делает ваш запрос и приведите код сущностей

Answer (score 3):

Рекурсивные запросы на LINQ невозможны.

Но вы можете добавить в БД представление (view) на основе этого запроса, после чего представить его коду как еще одну таблицу в БД.